# How to set browser language when using curl to retrieve contents?

Tags: php, curl, browser

It am using curl in php to get contents from external website. I am getting contents from websites like https://www.flickr.com/. The site will show different content (in different languages) for browsers in different languages. I want to get English content only. I have tried:

> ```
>   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.12) Gecko/2009070611 Firefox/3.0.12");
> ```

But it doesn't work. It retrieve Chinese contents instead. Any advice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the [`Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) request header using `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept-Language: en']);
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works for me with another langage. ;)